# Generate a table from a list

Tags: macros, matrices, tex-core, texstudio, arrays

Suppose I have a list of n items, is it possible to create a 2 by n+1 array?

I have my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

%Example 1
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}, ref=\arabic*]
    \item This is item 1.
    \item This is item 2.
    \item This is item 3.
\end{enumerate}

%Example 2
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}, ref=\arabic*]
    \item This is item 1.
    \item This is item 2.
    \item This is item 3.
    \item This is item 4.
    \item This is item 4.
    \item This is item 6.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Expected result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Why you not write directly as tables?

Comment: Because I don't know how many columns I need at the beginning. I could have a list with 10 items, 5 items etc. So I need it to constantly adapt as I change the list.

Comment: @AlanJones And how would you accommodate eleven columns on standard paper if the width of the item text is large?

Comment: @egreg, I am not interested in what the ```\item``` has. As long as say you create a list of 4 items, I want to to quick create a 2 by 5 table/array (numbered 1,2,3,4 and the bottom row is blank except for the first column)

Comment: @egreg also the width should be enough to accommodate say the numbers 1,2,3,....xx digits.

Comment: @AlanJones Do you want the table *in addition* to the enumerate?

Comment: @egreg what do you mean in addition to the enumerate?

Comment: @AlanJones I can think to two scenarios: you may want to print *either* the list *or* the table (by setting a boolean, I guess), or print both.

Comment: @egreg both. Because I will always have the list displayed first and then the table.

Comment: If you are an AUCTeX / Emacs user, you can use the orgtbl-insert-radio-table command and enable orgtbl mode. this allows to create a table interactively, insert, delete columns as you want and export it as a LaTeX table. This is a nice feature because the array accepts formulas possibly with symbolic calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a specific environment and add the table after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newlist{enumtable}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumtable]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}, ref=\arabic*}

\AddToHook{env/enumtable/after}{\printtable}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{}
 {
  \noindent
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|*{\int_eval:n { \value{enumtablei}+1 }}{X|}@{}}
  \hline
  Number \int_step_function:nN { \value{enumtablei} } \alanjones_addnumber:n \\
  \hline
  Item \prg_replicate:nn { \value{enumtablei} } { & } \\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \alanjones_addnumber:n { & #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumtable}
    \item This is item 1.
    \item This is item 2.
    \item This is item 3.
\end{enumtable}

%Example 2
\begin{enumtable}
    \item This is item 1.
    \item This is item 2.
    \item This is item 3.
    \item This is item 4.
    \item This is item 4.
    \item This is item 6.
\end{enumtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your LaTeX doesn't recognize `\AddToHook`, don't worry: also load `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and replace the line

```
\AddToHook{env/enumtable/after}{\printtable}
```

with

```
\AfterEndEnvironment{enumtable}{\printtable}
```

However, it's better if you update your TeX system.

---

In order to print a *single* table at the end:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newlist{enumtable}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[enumtable]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}\hspace{4mm}, ref=\arabic*}

\AddToHook{env/enumtable/after}{\maketable\AtEndDocument{\printtable}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \g__alanjones_finaltable_box
\NewDocumentCommand{\maketable}{}
 {
  \vbox_gset:Nn \g__alanjones_finaltable_box
   {
    \noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}|*{\int_eval:n { \value{enumtablei}+1 }}{X|}@{}}
    \hline
    Number \int_step_function:nN { \value{enumtablei} } \alanjones_addnumber:n \\
    \hline
    Item \prg_replicate:nn { \value{enumtablei} } { & } \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \alanjones_addnumber:n { & #1 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\printtable}{}
 {
  \par
  \addvspace{\topsep}
  \box_use:N \g__alanjones_finaltable_box
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumtable}
    \item This is item 1.
    \item This is item 2.
    \item This is item 3.
    \item This is item 4.
    \item This is item 4.
    \item This is item 6.
\end{enumtable}

Some text here.

\end{document}
```

The modifications for older versions of LaTeX are similar to what's been said above.

Comment: I can't seem to run it, I get the following error ```Undefined control sequence. \AddToHook``` Also is it possible to call the function that prints the table at the end of the document? Because I will only have one list at the start of the document and would like the table called for at the end the document.

Comment: @AlanJones You should update your TeX system. However, I'll add a different implementation for older versions of LaTeX.

Comment: I will update it now, how do I call the environment/function so that it prints the table at the very end rather than straight after?

Comment: @AlanJones That's a very different requirement!

Comment: Fair enough, now i have to study your work. I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: @AlanJones Is it just one table or several of them? In the latter case, how do you distinguish them from one another?

Comment: I always have one list at the beginning of the document and need a replica of that list in table form at the end of the document. But in my WME I just gave two examples and expected result. So just one table.

Comment: @AlanJones I added the requested provision to print the table at the end.

Answer (score 0):

With [knitr](https://yihui.org/knitr/):

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F>>=
items = c("foo","bah","baz")
@
\begin{itemize}
  \item
<<results="asis", echo=F>>=
  cat(items, sep="\n\\item ")
@
\end{itemize}
<<results="asis", echo=F>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(t(items)),include.rownames=FALSE)
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: I need it with the foo, bah and baz. Also I need the items displayed strictly in an ```\begin{enumerate} \item \item \end{enumerate} ```

Comment: @AlanJones Sorry, is not clear to me what you mean in the first sentence. The items and the table have already that  words. With respect the second sentence, it solved  replacing "itemize"  by "enumerate" in lines 6 and 11.